# How do I keep an Android BLE connection alive through app Destroy

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Basically I want to be able to open an android app that I have created. Send some data to the serial port (which I have all working so far) then exit the app and when I come back to it; send some more data without having to go through the connection process again.

Is there some secret in the .createbond method? I know it has been done before. I have a pebble watch that uses the app basically only for connection attempt and then once I exit I get notifications all day. How does this work with a BLE device. I need some ingisht. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You do this by using a service. Create a service, connect to the device from the service and then send any data you want from the app to the service to send to the device. This way you will maintain a connection to the device independent of the app.